# Create a matrix of integers given a set of strings and a dictionary, in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matrix

I have a set of strings (as a Nx1 matrix) and a dictionary(Mx1) that contains all the words that are there in the strings.
eg:

```
strings= ['i went to the mall'; 'i am hungry']
dictionary = ['i','went','to','the', 'mall','am','hungry']
```

I want to create a matrix (of size MxN) where the cell contains 1 if the corresponding word is present in the corresponding tweet. How could I do it in matlab?

I tried doing this:

```
for i=1:len_of_dict
    for j=1:len_of_str
         temp=strfind(string1(j),dict(i));
         x=find(cellfun(@isempty,temp));
         xx = isempty(x);
         if(xx~=0)
             vec(i,j)=1;
         end      
    end
end
```

But the vector that i got is not correct. Pleas help!

Answer (score 0):

String sould be stored as cell arrays. then you can use `strsplit` to break the tweets then use `ismember` for checking presence of each word in tweets.

```
strings= {'i went to the mall'; 'i am hungry'};
dictionary = {'i','went','to','the', 'mall','am','hungry'};

splitted_strings = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,' '), strings, 'UniformOutput', false);

presence = cellfun(@(s) ismember(dictionary, s), splitted_strings, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You can use `vertcat` to convert result to a matrix:

```
out = vertcat(presence {:})
```

result:

```
1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   1
```